# MySQL not using index

Tags: mysql, indexing, filesort

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TxtDila` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
  `Datum` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Datum` (`Datum`),
...
  FULLTEXT KEY `Titulek` (`Titulek`,`Anotace`,`Txt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

When I ran:
EXPLAIN SELECT ID FROM TxtDila USE INDEX ( Datum ) ORDER BY Datum

I get:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  TxtDila ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    214603  Using filesort
```

Even when I try 
EXPLAIN SELECT ID FROM TxtDila use index(Datum) USE INDEX ( Datum ) ORDER BY Datum
I can see filesort.

Table has 200.000 records, and about 700MB. I have fulltext index.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read 200,000 records' ID fields (the entire table). The index `Datum` doesn't include the ID fields, so whichever way you do it this is going to involve reading the ID fields from disc. You're telling MySQL to use the index on Datum to order the records, then read them. That pretty much means doing up to 200,000 reads from the disc. MySQL decides (correctly) that it's less work just to read all the `(ID, datum)` pairs from the table in one big read and order them in memory.

I suggest making the `Datum` index a multi-column index on `(Datum, ID)`.

Comment: You need the multi-column index, as suggested, because MyISAM doesn't automatically include primary key in index like InnoDB does.

Comment: @Marcus, thanks for the pointer. I am not particularly expert at the topic of hard disk access strategies, so seeks/reads/etc passes me by a little. Agreed if the table were InnoDB there would not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are usually used when you have a `WHERE` clause in your query. An alternative would be to use the `SELECT... FORCE INDEX` syntax. You can read about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 0):

A fulltext index isn't really an index used in normal queries...just for full text search (thus the name).

Also, in this case you get the filesort because you're sorting.

You don't use the primary key index on id because you aren't restricting your query in any way - this query will always return the entire table.